# Magento 2.3: How to create a custom filter?

Tags: category, magento2.3, filter, product-page

I'm having a requirement that is related to filtering the products. By default, when the user clicks on the category, it will be redirected to the corresponding product listing page.

But my requirement is, when the user clicks on the parent category on megamenu, we wanted to display a pop-up which having the filtering option like size, brand, price, etc., instead of showing the product listing page.

How can I achieve that?

Could anyone please help me with this?